# Messaging.MassEmailMessage class doesn't work when we set a list of case ids as whatids. It works fine if we don't set whatids

Tags: apex-email-service, apex

Please help me fix my issue with Messaging.MassEmailMessage class. It doesn't work when I set a list of contactIds as my targetObjectIds and set a list of case ids as whatids. It works fine if i don't set whatids.

//This is a Utility Class that sends out eamils when a ticket comment is update
//June 14, 2014

```
public class MassEmailHelper {

   public MassEmailHelper(){}

   public static void notifyAll(List<Case> ticketsToNotify, Boolean setActivity)
{
        Integer num = 0;
        MassLists__c massEmail;
        List<MassLists__c>massEmailList = new List<MassLists__c>();

        Set<ID> ParentTicketIDs = new Set<ID>();
        List<Contact> ContactListIDs = new List<Contact>();

        List<Id> CaseAccountIds = new List<Id>();

      /* //Get the Account ID associated with the ticket comment that has been updated
      ParentTicketList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Notify_All__c, Mass_Notification__c, 
                       Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN: ParentTicketIDs];*/

       for(Case c: ticketsToNotify)
            if(c.Notify_All__c==true)
                CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);

       System.debug('The size of account List is: :' + CaseAccountIds.size());
      //Get all the ids for the contacts to email. Bascially, all support site users from the Accounts for the tickets  
      //ContactsToEmailIdList = [Select Id, AccountId From Contact where  AccountID in :CaseAccountIds and Receive_Support_Notifications__c=true];

        Map<Id, Account> mapAccounts = new Map<ID, Account>([Select Id, (Select Id, Email From Contacts where 
                                     Receive_Support_Notifications__c=true) from Account where Id IN :CaseAccountIds]);


        Integer batchSize =240;
        List<Messaging.Email> mailList = new List<Messaging.Email>();
        Messaging.Massemailmessage mail = new Messaging.Massemailmessage();  
        List<Id> contactList=new List<Id>();
        Id[] caseList = new List<Id>();
        string TemplateName = '{Customer} Ticket has been updated';
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> fetching email template');
       EmailTemplate e = [select Id,Name,Subject,body, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where name like :templateName+'%'];
     //  templateName='test4';
       // EmailTemplate e = [select Id,Name,Subject,body, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where name like :templateName];
        Account accWithContacts;
        mail.setTemplateId(e.Id);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Set initial params for email');

        for(Case caseObj:ticketsToNotify ){
            if(caseObj.Notify_All__c == true){
                    accWithContacts = mapAccounts!=null ? mapAccounts.get(caseObj.AccountId): null;
                    System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX accWithContacts  '+accWithContacts );
                    if( accWithContacts !=NULL && accWithContacts.Contacts!=NULL)
                        for(Contact contactObj: accWithContacts.Contacts){
                           if(contactList.size()>batchSize){
                           System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX I am in 55');
                                mail.setWhatIds(caseList);   
                                mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactList);                           
                                mailList.add(mail);
                                mail = new Messaging.Massemailmessage();
                                mail.setTemplateId(e.Id);
//                              mail.setSaveAsActivity(setActivity);
                                contactList = new List<Id>();
                                caseList=new List<Id>();
                            }
                            caseList.add(caseObj.Id);
                            contactList.add(contactObj.Id);
                           /* insertUpdateTicketInfo(num, setActivity,massEmail, contactObj,e,
                            caseObj,massEmailList );                            
                            num++;*/
                     }
                     System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX caseList '+caseList);
                     System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX contactList'+contactList);
                }
            else{
                                       System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX I am in 76');
                    if(caseObj.ContactId!=null){
                                               System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX I am in 78');
                        if(contactList.size()>batchSize){
                                                   System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX I am in 80');
                            mail.setWhatIds(caseList);
                            mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactList);
                            mailList.add(mail);
                            mail = new Messaging.Massemailmessage();
                            mail.setTemplateId(e.Id);
  //                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(setActivity);
                            contactList = new List<Id>();
                            caseList=new List<Id>();                    
                        }
                        caseList.add(caseObj.Id);
                        contactList.add(caseObj.ContactId);
              //          mailPrimaryContact(setActivity, mail, caseObj, e, mailList);
                         System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX caseList2 '+caseList);
                     System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX contactList2'+contactList)  ;            
                    }
                    if(caseObj.Additional_Contact_1__c!=null){
                       if(contactList.size()>batchSize){
                            mail.setWhatIds(caseList);  
                            mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactList);                       
                            mailList.add(mail);
                            mail = new Messaging.Massemailmessage();
                            mail.setTemplateId(e.Id);
    //                      mail.setSaveAsActivity(setActivity);                            
                            contactList = new List<Id>();
                            caseList=new List<Id>();                        
                        }
                        caseList.add(caseObj.Id);
                        contactList.add(caseObj.Additional_Contact_1__c);
//                       mailPrimaryContact(setActivity, mail, caseObj, e, mailList);
                    }
                    if(caseObj.Additional_Contact_2__c!=null){
                        if(contactList.size()>batchSize){
                            mail.setWhatIds(caseList);                          
                            mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactList);
                            mailList.add(mail);
                            mail = new Messaging.Massemailmessage();
                            mail.setTemplateId(e.Id);
      //                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(setActivity);                            
                            contactList = new List<Id>();
                            caseList=new List<Id>();                                                        
                        }
                        caseList.add(caseObj.Id);
                        contactList.add(caseObj.Additional_Contact_2__c);
//                        mailPrimaryContact2(setActivity, mail, caseObj, e, mailList);
                    }
              }
        }
          system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Case List Size '+caseList.size()); 
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Contact List Size '+contactList.size()); 
        if(contactList.size()>0){
        System.debug('XXXXXXXXXXXXX caseList 131'+caseList);

            mail.setWhatIds(caseList);
            mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactList);
  //        mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mailList.add(mail);
        }


        //send email
            System.Debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> The mail List size is: '  +mailList.size() );
            if(mailList!=null && !mailList.isEmpty() && mailList.size() > 0){           
                for(Messaging.Email m: mailList)
                        System.debug('Contact List size '+((Messaging.Massemailmessage)m).getTargetObjectIds().size()
                        +' and what id size '+((Messaging.Massemailmessage)m).getWhatIds().size()); 
                 try{

                      List<Messaging.Sendemailresult> srs =  Messaging.sendEmail(mailList, false); 
                      system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> After mass email');     
                      for(Messaging.Sendemailresult sr : srs)
                          if(!sr.isSuccess())
                            system.debug('Messaging failed '+sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage());

                  }catch (Exception ex){
                       system.debug('A fatal exception occurred '+ex);
                  }
              }


            /**
            if(massEmailList!=null && !massEmailList.isEmpty() && massEmailList.size() > 0)
                system.debug('Number of emails to email from update Ticket Comments is: ' +massEmailList.size());
            insert massEmailList;
            **/

   }//end of email method



      public static void insertUpdateTicketInfo(Integer num, Boolean setActivity, MassLists__c massEmail, Contact contactObj,EmailTemplate e,
      Case caseObj,List<MassLists__c>massEmailList ){

       massEmail = new MassLists__c();
       massEmail.Set_Activity__c = setActivity;                                                        
       massEmail.filterCode__c = 'CDT'; 
       massEmail.Name = 'MassCommentUpdateTicket'+num;
       massEmail.ContactID__c = contactObj.Id;
       massEmail.TemplateID__c = e.Id ;
       massEmail.TicketID__c = caseObj.Id;                         
       massEmailList.add(massEmail);
    }
 }
```

I am using cases for the whatIds. I know that I can use Messaging.SingleEmailMessage. However, for this particular scenario, I need to use Messaging.MassEmailMessage. Please let me know why Messaging.MassEmailMessage is not working with cases as whatIds.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you specify the error you are getting while sending mail ?

Comment: I only shows the status as Complete: Failed in the Mass email monitoring logs. Is there any way i can check the error else where ?

Comment: you could check the email log files for checking any errors. is OWD for case object private or read ony?

Comment: Are you saying that you see no output from the `system.debug('Messaging failed '+sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage());` immediately after the send call?

Comment: The OWD is private for the case object. I do not see any logs in Mass email logs or the regular email logs. I do not see any output from the system.debug('Messaging failed '+sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage()); -- wierd case

Comment: see if changing the OWD to read only works, since it may be possible that mails are not getting sent if you are accessing any merge fields from the case object.